# Referencing Outside Projects In Android

Tags: android, jar, apk

I am trying to write a modular extensible application to deploy in Android.  The idea is to provide an API to allow the creation of custom functionality for the app that may include custom layouts and other resources.  This custom functionality will be loaded, at runtime, from another location (e.g. SD Card).

Currently I am able to load .jar files from this location and work with them as I like, unfortunately I can only include references to layouts and resources that are also present in the "Main" project.

I have been unable to find a good way to reference an entire library project, resources included.  I essentially want each custom piece to contain all the resources it needs to display and run itself.

Right now I am toying with the idea of including an "Assets" project that can be referenced by each of the modules to be a central area to store layouts and other resources.  Unfortunately this would require me to have a project that must be loaded by any other project that needs to be built.

Another idea was to include the layouts, images and strings, along with the jar files, in a folder and load those at run time.  I don't think this will work well since the layouts seem to be pre-processed at compile time in some way and cannot be inflated at run time.

Does anyone know a way for me to include all the resources and code into a single, dynamically loadable, file that I can then access at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know a way for me to include all the resources and code into a single, dynamically loadable, file that I can then access at runtime?

That is not supported. It is rather likely that it will never be supported, though it is possible that it might work with the new build system that is under development.

Comment: Well, that is unfortunate.  I guess I will have to explore some of my work-arounds for the time being.

Thanks for the answer.